# Problems with angular JSON responses in app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

```
**JS Code**
Getting a problem in fetching JSON object value from php and displaying it in console.
```

I have implemented a post method with the value user in it which consist of email and password. In php file i am validating it and returning value to json object but it do not show any value.

Can anyone find what is wrong with the code.

I have defined ggApp to my body tag

```
var ggApp = angular.module('ggApp', []);

ggApp.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,$http){
$scope.loginApp = function(user){
console.log(user);
$http.post('/getgrocers/cred_files/login.php', user).success(function(data){
console.log(data);
}).error(function(data){
console.log(data);
});
}
})
<div class="sign-in" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<form method="post">
<input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="user.email"/>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.pass"/>
<input type="submit" value="Log In" ng-click="loginApp(user)">
</form>
</div>




**PHP Code**



<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$userq = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$data1 = "";
if($userq->email == "chandra****@gmail.com" && $userq->pass == "***"){
$data1 = "secess";
}
else 
$data1 = "error";
}
$dd = json_encode($data1);
print_r($dd);
return json_encode($dd); 
?>
```

Comment: I removed your GMail email and password. Waiting on a peer review. You should do it first if you see it.

Comment: @JoeMartella thanks for your help... i litrally forgot it to remove from code

Answer (score 0):

You should `echo` the json not `return` it and get rid of `print_r`

Try changing:

```
$dd = json_encode($data1);
print_r($dd);
return json_encode($dd);
```

To

```
$dd = json_encode($data1);
echo json_encode($dd);
```

Comment: I did this also in beginning but it do not show any output

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network tab. Should find clues there what is happening

Comment: Also you aren't preventing the default event on submit click...try using ng-submit. I bet the page is refreshing

Comment: i tried this but it still showing me the blank result... this is the screenshot may b u can help... http://sysnotech.com/getgrocers/screenshot.png

Comment: thanks dude i figure out the problem there was a problem with my php code.... your help is apriciated

Comment: Always inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network tab. If it was 500 in php would easily see it there